# Emacs, Zsh and Ansi-Term -- weird chars

Tags: shell, emacs, zsh

My issue is illustrated in the follow images:

This is the visual representation I get in my iTerm of my Zsh shell, with the same font as used in Emacs:

[image: iTerm output]

This my my Emacs output using ansi-term:

[image: Emacs]

I've been looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303611/emacs-multi-term-not-displaying-special-characters-correctly) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8918910/weird-character-zsh-in-emacs-terminal)... and none of the suggestions helped me.

My iTerm and Emacs does not share the same color theme, incase someone was wondering about the color difference in the screenshots.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess your prompt is echoing escape characters understood by iTerm but not by ansi-term.  Try this: `echo $PS1`.

Comment: Returns no output for me.

Comment: OK, zsh can use another prompt, try this: `echo $PROMPT` and `echo $RPROMPT`.

Comment: I got this ``39m$(build_prompt) %{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)``

Comment: Your prompt is being set in your `.zshrc`, but in theory it should adapt to the terminal.  Try commenting out (putting a `#` in front of) any mention of the prompt in `.zshrc` and then re-start your ansi-term.  Unfortunately the prompt won't look pretty in iTerm, but should be more acceptable in ansi-term.

Comment: There's no mention of prompt in my zshrc. I believe it might have something to do with the official cocoa app of Emacs, doesn't support UTF-16, or something similar.